# Including a c header in c++ while maintaining functionality

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple c program which handles sockets. It includes the header "string.h". It takes a char* as an input and sends that through the socket to a server process on the localhost. 
I want to include this program in a c++ program which is already built, and uses regular c++ strings throughout the code. Is there a way to use char* and strings in the same program, or at least keep the char* functionality confined to the c header?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use `char*` and `std::strings` in same program. Infact you can convert `std::string` to `char *`.

```
std::string a("jacklong101");
char *cstr = a.c_str();
```

Comment: When I try it like that, I get several errors that look something like this: Client.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'